# SELECT clause using IN ... very slow?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

Could you guys please review the following query to an Oracle DB and point out what's wrong:

```
SELECT t1.name FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.empno IN (1, 2, 3, …, 200)
```

**Query statistics:**

- Time taken: 10.53 seconds.

**Indices:**

- `t2.empno` is indexed.
- `t1.id` is indexed.
- `t2.id` is indexed.

Update

---

The above query was just a sample replica of the query i use. 
Here below in a more true form

**Explain Plan**
[image: Explain Plan]

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT_REPRESENTATION_SK 
FROM 
    Product_Representation pr 
    , Design_Object do
    , Files files  
    ,EPS_STATUS epsStatus 
    ,EPS_ERROR_CODES epsError
    ,VIEW_TYPE viewTable  
WHERE  
    pr.DESIGN_OBJECT_SK = do.DESIGN_OBJECT_SK 
    AND  pr.LAYER_NAME !='Layer 0' 
    AND  epsStatus.EPS_STATUS_SK = pr.EPS_STATUS  
    AND epsError.EPS_ERROR_CODE = pr.EPS_ERROR_CODE 
    AND viewTable.VIEW_TYPE_ID = pr.VIEW_TYPE_ID 
    AND  files.pim_id = do.PIM_ID 
    AND  do.DESIGN_OBJECT_ID IN
        (
147086,149924,140458,135068,145197,134774,141837,138568,141731,138772,143769,141739,149113,148809,141072,141732,143974,147076,143972,141078,141925,134643,139701,141729,147078,139120,137097,147072,138261,149700,149701,139127,147070,149702,136766,146829,135762,140155,148459,138061,138762.............................................  200 such numbers
        )
```

**Indexed Colums:**

```
pr.DESIGN_OBJECT_SK
do.DESIGN_OBJECT_SK
do.DESIGN_OBJECT_ID
files.pim_id
```

Table

---

```
TABLE "PIM"."DESIGN_OBJECT" 
(   
"DESIGN_OBJECT_SK" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PIM_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DESIGN_OBJECT_TYPE_SK" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DESIGN_OBJECT_ID" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DIVISION_CD" NUMBER(*,0), 
"STAT_IND" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"STAT_CHNG_TMST" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"CRTD_BY" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE), 
"CRT_TMST" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"MDFD_BY" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE), 
"CHNG_TMST" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"UPDATE_CNT" NUMBER(*,0), 
"GENDER" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 

 PRIMARY KEY ("DESIGN_OBJECT_SK")
)
TABLESPACE "PIM"  ENABLE, 

FOREIGN KEY ("DESIGN_OBJECT_TYPE_SK")
    REFERENCES "PIM"."DESIGN_OBJECT_TYPE" ("DESIGN_OBJECT_TYPE_SK")
        ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 

FOREIGN KEY ("PIM_ID")
    REFERENCES "PIM"."FILES" ("PIM_ID")
        ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE

)
```

Table 2

---

```
CREATE TABLE "PIM"."PRODUCT_REPRESENTATION" 
(
"PRODUCT_REPRESENTATION_SK" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DESIGN_OBJECT_SK" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"VIEW_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"LAYER_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
"STAT_IND" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"STAT_CHNG_TMST" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"CRTD_BY" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE), 
"CRT_TMST" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"MDFD_BY" VARCHAR2(45 BYTE), 
"CHNG_TMST" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"UPDATE_CNT" NUMBER(*,0), 
"EPS_STATUS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"EPS_GENERATED_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
"EPS_ERROR_CODE" NUMBER, 
"EPS_ERROR_DETAILS" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"DEEPSERVER_ASSET_LAYER_ID" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
"PRODUCT_REPRESENTATION_LOC" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 

 PRIMARY KEY ("PRODUCT_REPRESENTATION_SK")
)
TABLESPACE "PIM"  ENABLE, 

FOREIGN KEY ("DESIGN_OBJECT_SK")
    REFERENCES "PIM"."DESIGN_OBJECT" ("DESIGN_OBJECT_SK") 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
FOREIGN KEY ("VIEW_TYPE_ID")
    REFERENCES "PIM"."VIEW_TYPE" ("VIEW_TYPE_ID")
        ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 

CONSTRAINT "EPS_ERROR_CODE_FK"
FOREIGN KEY ("EPS_ERROR_CODE")
     REFERENCES "PIM"."EPS_ERROR_CODES" ("EPS_ERROR_CODE") 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
CONSTRAINT "EPS_STATUS_FK" 
FOREIGN KEY ("EPS_STATUS")
    REFERENCES "PIM"."EPS_STATUS" ("EPS_STATUS_SK") 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
)
```

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: any execution plan?  seems like the parse may be expensive, not so much the query part. (plus you have an extra comma - which i assume is a paste problem )

Comment: also, maybe just an artifact of your example.. but you should use <200 and not that big IN string...

Comment: t2.empno in (1,2,3,........,200) != t2.empno > 0 and t2.empno < 201 ?

Comment: @Sudhakar: Is that your actual query? Then you could have `t2.empno BETWEEN 1 AND 200` or the similar ones that @Randy and @heximal suggested.

Comment: In general, the SQL engine has to read through the entire index when using an IN clause.  BETWEEN is faster.

Comment: @Sudhakar: Can you provide the execution plan? And the tables' definitions? There may some other slowing factor. For example, `t2.empno` and `t2.id` may be indexed but the query could benefit perhaps from a `id, empno` or an `empno, id` index.

Comment: I have to assume his (1,2,3,...,200) isn't actually as simple in practice as his example here. You are all certainly correct that if he *is* just interested in `BETWEEN 1 AND 200` that he should use that... but in practice I would assume he uses non-sequential and incomplete sets for the real query.... assuming he's looking for particular rows by a set of ID's

Comment: @Mathew PK : yes indeed . the IN value are not sequential

Comment: Sudhakar: small question; Why `do.DESIGN_OBJECT_ID` is a `VARCHAR` if you store numbers there?

Comment: More questions: do you have indices on the other fields that are used in the (hidden) JOINs? Did you try to rewrite the query using `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`? Did you try my `EXISTS` approach?

Answer (score 8):

Lets forget for a moment the `empno BETWEEN 1 and 200` suggestion and assume that you have you have `t2.empno IN (3,7,...,5209)` (200 entries).

You could also write your query (which is a hidden JOIN query) to the **non-equivalent** EXISTS query which would show same results (but possibly fewer rows) and should be faster than the JOIN:

```
SELECT
    t1.name
FROM
    t1
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
          AND t2.empno IN (3,7,...,5209)
      )
```

---

**(Wild speculation)**

If on the other hand, it's not even `t2.empno IN (3,7,...,5209)` but `t2.empno IN (SELECT tx.empno FROM tx WHERE someConditions)` **and** you are using MySQL, then this is the root of your problem (MySQL is known to not handle `field IN (SELECT f FROM x)` in the best possible way). So, you could change the query into:

```
SELECT
    t1.name
FROM
    t1
  JOIN t2
    ON t2.id = t2.id
  JOIN tx
    ON tx.empno = t2.empno
WHERE
    someConditions
```

or even to:

```
SELECT
    t1.name
FROM
    t1
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM t2
          JOIN tx
            ON tx.empno = t2.empno
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
          AND someConditions
      )
```

Comment: +1 an excellent point about MySQL and its handling of `IN(subquery)`

Answer (score 7):

The first thing that is wrong is using implict join syntax. That is a SQL antipattern.

If you have a large list in the IN clause, have you tried putting them in a table instead and using a join?

What database? Have you looked at your explain plan or execution plan to see where the slowdown is?

Comment: +1 putting the `IN (..)` in a table may improve performance depending on the size of all the tables here... Or, if you have SQL2008 you can send them in a TVP

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the cross-join.

try this

```
SELECT
    t1.name
FROM
    t1
JOIN t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    t2.empno IN (1,...,200)
```

**EDIT**: After you edit, seeing your multiple tables in the cartesian products, it is probably very important that you use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: This is a valid answer to the question. Downvoter, please provide feedback.

Comment: I have not downvoted as this is a good suggestion. But it is not an answer for the slow performance. For such a simple query, either way to write the query should result in the same execution plan.

Comment: @ypercube you may be right but it's still speculation on his RDBMS and his actual tables (rather than his, I assume, over-simplified example here). Nonetheless, using a proper `JOIN` may help his RDBMS plan the query and increase speed more than scanning 200 `int`s. Using the `JOIN` is certainly proper practice and may yield the results he can deal with.

Comment: I agree, `JOIN` is proper practice.

Comment: the thing i see is that t2.id = t2.id is obviously incorrect, and the syntax here is equivalent otherwise...  not much of an answer.

Comment: @Randy thanks for pointing out the typo, edited! This syntax *may* produce an equivalent query plan... but it's still proper syntax and may improve perf.